# Suggestions With Object Structure From Parsing

Tags: java, object-oriented-analysis

I'm parsing data from web pages (is it a project, and mine was do a card game app), and all cards share common info (as name, flavour text, text, type, etc). But some  has its unique fields (like creature cards and its ATK/DEF). But I don't know the type until I'm parsing already. So far I came up with 2 approaches:

1. Start the parsing, and create a general Object(like Card, with the common information) and when I reach the "type" field, I create a specific object (for example, Creature, extending Card), give the Card object, and continue the parsing filling up the specific object.
2. Have a general object with all the information possible, and after finished parsing, create the specific object.

Comment: How about, parse **then** create the object? A possible solution would be to use a Map (key = field, value = field value) and feed that to a creature factory

Comment: You mean, one Map for each time I parse? So, after parsing, get the type value and then create the specific object?

Comment: I mean put the parsing result in a map, yes